# Heroku and Iris couch vs Cloudant

Tags: heroku, couchdb, cloudant, iriscouch

Have you got any experience/thoughts on using Iriscouch or Cloudant with Heroku?
Do you have to use Cloudant (as it is offered as an add-on)?

What are the pros/cons?

I'm working on an application that is heavy in geo information and needs to be distributed globally. Is any of the above mentioned faster (lower latency) in any particular region (mostly interested in Europe and Australia)?

Thx

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what Iriscouch have to offer in this regard, but Cloudant's search feature lets you [search in geographic regions](http://examples.cloudant.com/simplegeo_places/_design/geo/search.html). Also, when you sign up you can choose where you want your account to live. You could pick one in Europe or one that is close to wherever Heroku's servers are. If it's not the right place, you can always move later.

Comment: Regarding geo-distribution on Cloudant, you could set up several multi-tenant accounts, each hosted on different datacentres, and replicate between them. For Europe and Australia, Jenever (Amsterdam) and Sling (Singapore) are probably best as they both run on SoftLayer and so replication can use the internal SL network. In this setup, your application would need to direct requests to the appropriate account.  


Dedicated customers can have true geo-load balancing and there are more options around cluster location (including e.g. Sydney).